# How can I set a max width to a "display:table-cell" element?

Tags: html, css, scale, tablelayout

My goal is to get a sidebar layout which should scale based on the browser window width. Some parts should have a scaled width, others should have a static width and some should scale but with a min/max-width. (It also would be great if some would expand based on the content within)

The html:

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="sidebar">at least 90px width<br/>not more than 130px width</div>
    <div id="content">scale</div>
    <div id="logo">should be static 60px</div>
    <div id="sidebar2">at least 90px width</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#table {
display: inline-table;
width: 100%;
}

#row {
display: table-row;
}

#table #row div {
display: table-cell;
}

#sidebar {
width: 10%;
min-width: 90px;
max-width: 130px;
}

#content {
width: 70%;
}

#logo {
min-width: 60px;
background-color: #FAB6B8;
}

#sidebar2 {
min-width: 90px;
width: 20%;
}
```

The issues:

1. It appears that `max-width` has no effect on dom-elements with `display:table-cell` assigned. (I guess)

   I tried to work with another div, spans around the actual cell div.
   This causes the problem, that the cell scales perfectly, but the left side of the content div will not stick to the first sidebar. (Same problem, if I put the "max-width div" inside the cell)

   Working with a `float: left layout` doesn’t work either. (Float breaks if window gets too small; don’t scale, if I use a div to protect it)

   Is there a way to work around this without using js?
2. Put in a div in #row with no further CSS will work for a div, which expand based on content. Sadly if there is just text in it breaks after every word. How can I prevent this and be able to set a max width and hide the overflow?

Comment: Can I ask why you need display:table-cell? Whatever you are using that for can probably be done differently.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
display:table-cell is necessary because I can't use float:left to get multiple Elements in a horizontal row. I guess there is no other way to achieve that except of this methods.

Comment: Float:left will get everything into a row. As well as display:inline.

Comment: display:inline and float:left doesn’t work. Float:left will cause the layout to break when window gets too small and display:inline lineup the next div with the last line in the previous div.

Comment: display:inline-block and verticle-align:middle;

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer by myself:

The key is to apply absolute width to the elements, which should get a max width.
It's not perfect, because the divs with an absolute width don’t scale, until the one with a relative width reach their min-widths but I guess it’s the only way.

So simple.
Sorry for the trouble...